# Создание глобальных хуков клавиш

Tags: c#, winrt

Ищу пример того, как сделать глобальные горячие клавиши средствами WinRT.

Видел решения на Win32 API, но это не особо спортивно.

Поднимаю вопрос, так как тема еще интересна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRT предоставляет весьма ограниченный API. Глобальную горячую клавишу (на всю систему) с помощью него сделать нельзя (да и доступ к Win32 API оттуда тоже закрыт, насколько я помню, т.к. WinRT частично и является заменой Win32). Горячую клавишу можно сделать только в пределах самого приложения.

Comment: Хотелось бы надеяться, что это устаревшая информация или недостоверная)

Comment: Доступ к Win32 закрыт только для Метро-приложений. В обычном десктопном можно пользоваться и WinRT, и Win32 одновременно.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю WinRT это обертка над Win32 и да приложение десктопное

Comment: @Сергей: Наоборот. Глобальный хук — это низкоуровневый хак из глубин тёмной древности, когда все программы бежали в общей памяти, и каждая программа могла испортить жизнь всей системе необычайно изобретательными путями (например, подсмотреть пароли или разрушить память). В WinRT, как более современной архитектуре, все программы, слава Баллмеру, изолированы, и хакерские обходные пути закрыты.

Хотите быть современным клёвым чуваком — используйте официальное API.

Comment: @VladD: А не верно ли это только для магазинных приложений? Очень бы хотелось верить так как моей программе как раз нужен доступ к клавиатуре а в лучшем случае и к контролам других приложений. Мне казалось, что WinRT позволит это делать красиво и официально вместо использования низкоуровневых древних хаков.

Comment: @Сергей: Смотрите. Если программа _хочет_ дать легитимный контроль над своими контролами, она предоставляет вам своё API. Если вы через «чёрный ход» перехватываете клавиатурный ввод, адресованный не вашему приложению, как пользователь может знать, что вы делаете это с хорошими намерениями, а не просто следите за ним?

Любая десктоп-программа, устанавливающая глобальный клавиатурный хук, в принципе не сможет получить Vista Logo (и более поздние) от Microsoft. Вмешивание в дела других программ официально не одобряется и не поддерживается.